# Create transparent form

Tags: android, firemonkey, c++builder

I work with FireMonkey in C++Builder, and I'm trying to make a transparent form, so that the components that are on it are displayed, but in the space where there are no components you can see what is below the form (transparent)...

I have set the `Transparency` property of the form to `true`, but the areas of the form that should be transparent look **BLACK**.

I have searched the Internet and found solutions for Delphi, but none for C++.

I tried to include this in the manifest:

```xml
SetActivityAttribute(MYFormTransparent ,android:theme, @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar)
```

but still, the same issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem that was introduced in 10.3 Rio. It has already been reported to Embarcadero (unfortunately, it has been closed as "works as expected"):

[RSP-22314: Transparency Property](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22314)

Marco Cantu commented on that report:

> Sorry for not commenting sooner. We have done some research on it for the last update, but decided to defer a fix.
>
> The core issue (in short) is that we use Android SurfaceView and this is a limitation of that platform control (only 2 SurfaceView instances are available). We are using this platform element as it allows us to mix styled and platforms controls (a feature we introduced in 10.30). **By chancing the internal implementation, the transparency become unavailable.**
>
> There is an alternative implementation of forms via TextureView, but so far our tests have shown that the speed of rendering 2 times slower, and we don't want to slow down all FMX applications on Android for this feature.
>
> There are some workarounds, one of them is to **use a frame instead of a form**. It works perfectly with transparency and uses less resources than separate form.
> For existing code the fast way is to **add a Layout to the form and have the controls inside it. When you need to display the form with transparency you can just move Layout from the specific form to main form as a child and align it on content Align = Content**.

Other commenters noted:

> I tested an **alternative with formStyle = popup and stylelookup = popupboxstyle
> with a rectangle in the form with transparency = 0.4** and some instructions to size the form with setBounds
>
> The result is acceptable

> As said by Herve Escriou, a work around is to **set your formstyle property of the form to "Popup"**. This will make the form transparent again. But this wil have the effect of the wsMaximized style not working properly. You can go around this by making the following code additions to your form: ...

Comment: Thank you very much for answering...

I had contemplated the Pop-Up option but it has the problem that touching the screen closes it even though it is not the action that is established for it.
Will try one of the other options.

Thank you so much. (forgive my english)